# Sentry SDK with Asp.Net 4.7.2 Not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, sentry

I have an Asp.Net web Api 2, using .net 4.7.2 version. And Sentry documents saying for .Net 4.7.2 version I can use Sentry nuget rather than ravenClient nuget. But when I installed Sentry nuget and used Sentry SDK, nothing working, no events are being sent to Sentry.
Below is my WebApi config file where I tried this Sentry.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        using (SentrySdk.Init(o =>
        {
            o.Dsn = myDsn;
            // When configuring for the first time, to see what the SDK is doing:
            o.Debug = true;
            // Set traces_sample_rate to 1.0 to capture 100% of transactions for performance monitoring.
            // We recommend adjusting this value in production.
            o.TracesSampleRate = 1.0;
        }))
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            //routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = RouteParameter.Optional, id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
            
            string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            SentrySdk.CaptureMessage("Something went wrong " + date);

        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have the Sentry initialization code within `using` block which is a common pattern for something like a CLI (so it flushes events before exiting).

With a long running process that's managed outside of your control like ASP.NET (not Core) you can call `Init` and then call `Dispose` or `Close` on the hook that's triggered before the process exits.

For example:

https://github.com/getsentry/examples/blob/81fb90b957ce9a8c1f6222d1603d0fa499ecba7e/dotnet/AspNetMvc5Ef6/Global.asax.cs#L21-L51

Comment: still it is not sending any events to Sentry.

Comment: Here's a description on how to debug such issues: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/issues/1118 on aspnet